# keras error in fit method : expected model_2 to have shape (None, 252, 252, 1) but got array with shape (300, 128, 128, 3)

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am building a image classifier for one-class classification in which i've used autoencoder.

While running this model I am getting this error by the line `autoencoder_model.fit`:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected model_2 to have shape (None, 252, 252, 1) but got array with shape (300, 128, 128, 3)

```python
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')

labels[0:376]=0 
names = ['cats']

input_shape=img_data[0].shape

X_train, X_test = train_test_split(img_data, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

inputTensor = Input(input_shape)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputTensor)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded_data = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

encoder_model = Model(inputTensor,encoded_data)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional
encoded_input = Input((4,4,8))
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded_input)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded_data = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

decoder_model = Model(encoded_input,decoded_data)

autoencoder_input = Input(input_shape)
encoded = encoder_model(autoencoder_input)
decoded = decoder_model(encoded)
autoencoder_model = Model(autoencoder_input, decoded)
autoencoder_model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', enter code here`loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder_model.fit(X_train, X_train,
        epochs=50,
        batch_size=32,
        validation_data=(X_test, X_test),
        callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])
```

Comment: Can you add example data or at least add the dimensions of your data?

Comment: input_shape -(128, 128, 3) , img_data.shape - (376, 128, 128, 3)

Comment: Please run a *fresh* script or kernel, and then 1) update your exact error message (will it still be `model_2` or something else?) and 2) include the output of the `autoencoder_model.summary()`, See [why this will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797837/keras-autoencoder-error-when-checking-target/47817911#47817911)

Comment: a note for @desertnaut I want clear my doubt, the output of the decoder is in grayscale??

Comment: In principle, an autoencoder's job is to re-create the original images, so the decoder's output should be whatever the input is...

Comment: is this is your assumption or your implementation experience

Comment: Neither - it is the *definition* of an autoencoder - see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) entry and [this Keras blog post](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the auto-encoder tries to re-create the original images, it seems you are reconstructing an image with different dimensions than the original, due to the fact to have only **two** `MaxPool2D` layers in your encoder and **three** `UpSampling2D` layers in your decoder.

When the auto-encoder tries to evaluate the loss of the reconstruction, it runs into an error due to a dimension miss-match.

Use this for your encoder and let us know if it works:

```
inputTensor = Input(input_shape)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputTensor)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded_data = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

encoder_model = Model(inputTensor,encoded_data)
```